# xml sitemap not displaying in xml format

Tags: xml, zend-framework

I want to display my sitemap in proper xml format but it displays in one line:

```
http://www.example.com/home 1.00 http://www.example.com/about 0.50 http://www.example.com/login 0.20 http://www. etc
```

not:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
      <url>
        <loc>http://www.example.com/home</loc>
        <priority>1.00</priority>
      </url>
      <url>
        <loc>http://www.example.com/about</loc>
        <priority>0.50</priority>
      </url>
      etc.
```

My code in SitemapController:

```
<?php
    class SitemapController extends Zend_Controller_Action
    {
            public function sitemapAction()
          {
            $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
            $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8');
          }    
    }
```

Code in sitemap.phtml:

```
<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
    xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
      <url>
        <loc>http://www.example.com/home</loc>
        <priority>1.00</priority>
      </url>
      <url> etc...
```

In my routes.ini:

```
resources.router.routes.sitemap.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route"
resources.router.routes.sitemap.route = "/sitemap.xml"
resources.router.routes.sitemap.defaults.module = "default"
resources.router.routes.sitemap.defaults.controller = "sitemap"
resources.router.routes.sitemap.defaults.action = "sitemap"
```

Based on earlier questions the disableLayout() in controller should have done it but has no effect on actual xml layout in view.

Comment: If you view source of the XML, is it how you want it then?

Comment: Yes in source it is okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're setting the correct content-type, it sounds like this is just down to how your browser is choosing to render XML data. Depending on what browser you're using, you might want to see if you can find an extension that will give you better XML formatting.

Comment: For other websites I see sitemaps are nicely displayed, so I don´t think it has anything to do with the browser? And it is the same for IE, Chrome or FF.

Comment: Can you provide the URL to your sitemap?

Comment: @zef How did you resolved the issue, I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @KasunRajapaksha I actually didn't. The (chrome) browser doesn't render xml layout. So you could try the suggestion Tim gave in the accepted answer or use an extentsion for the chrome browser as mentioned here: https://superuser.com/questions/972/displaying-xml-in-the-chrome-browser

Comment: @zef I resolved my issue by attaching opensource style sheet for XML