# Sitemap doesn't show as xml

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc, sitemap

I've got the following classes for my sitemap generation:

```
public class SitemapItem
{
    public SitemapItem(string url)
    {
        this.Url = url;
        this.AlternateLinks = new List<SiteMapAlternateLink>();
    }

    public string Url { get; set; }

    public DateTime? LastModified { get; set; }

    public ChangeFrequency? ChangeFrequency { get; set; }

    public float? Priority { get; set; }

    public List<SiteMapAlternateLink> AlternateLinks { get; set; }
}
```

And:

```
public class SiteMapAlternateLink
{
    public SiteMapAlternateLink(string url, string language)
    {
        this.Url = url;
        this.Language = language;
    }

    public string Url { get; set; }

    public string Language { get; set; }
}
```

Now in my controller I fill a list of SitemapItems and return it from the controller with the following code:

```
public class XmlSitemapResult : ActionResult
{
    private XNamespace nsSitemap = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9";
    private XNamespace nsXhtml = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";

    private IEnumerable<SitemapItem> _items;

    public XmlSitemapResult(IEnumerable<SitemapItem> items)
    {
        _items = items;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        string encoding = context.HttpContext.Response.ContentEncoding.WebName;
        XDocument sitemap = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", encoding, "yes"),
             new XElement(nsSitemap + "urlset", new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xhtml", nsXhtml),
                  from item in _items
                  select CreateItemElement(item)
                  )
             );

        context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/xml";
        context.HttpContext.Response.Charset = encoding;
        context.HttpContext.Response.Flush();
        context.HttpContext.Response.Write(sitemap.Declaration + sitemap.ToString());
    }

    private XElement CreateItemElement(SitemapItem item)
    {
        XElement itemElement = new XElement(nsSitemap + "url", new XElement(nsSitemap + "loc", item.Url.ToLower()));

        if (item.LastModified.HasValue)
            itemElement.Add(new XElement(nsSitemap + "lastmod", item.LastModified.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")));

        if (item.ChangeFrequency.HasValue)
            itemElement.Add(new XElement(nsSitemap + "changefreq", item.ChangeFrequency.Value.ToString().ToLower()));

        if (item.Priority.HasValue)
            itemElement.Add(new XElement(nsSitemap + "priority", item.Priority.Value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));

        foreach (var alternateLink in item.AlternateLinks)
        {
            itemElement.Add(new XElement(nsXhtml + "link", 
                new XAttribute("rel", "alternate"),
                new XAttribute("hreflang", alternateLink.Language),
                new XAttribute("href", alternateLink.Url)));
        }

        return itemElement;
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that in my browser I won't see the XML as XML. I'll just see text which doesn't get viewed with the standard XML Viewer. This happens in all browsers and it seems it happend from the moment I added the xhtml schema.

Hopefully somebody sees the problem, thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** If I remove everything that has to do with xhtml the browser DOES show it as a xml. Any ideas?

**EDIT2:** The html:

```
 <urlset xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <url>
    <loc>http://localhost:11149/en</loc>
    <changefreq>hourly</changefreq>
    <priority>0.6</priority>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://localhost:11149/en"/>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="nl" href="http://localhost:11149/nl"/>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://localhost:11149/en/buyandsell</loc>
    <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
    <priority>1</priority>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://localhost:11149/en/BuyAndSell"/>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="nl" href="http://localhost:11149/nl/BuyAndSell"/>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://localhost:11149/en/partner</loc>
    <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
    <priority>0.5</priority>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://localhost:11149/en/Partner"/>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="nl" href="http://localhost:11149/nl/Partner"/>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://localhost:11149/en/news</loc>
    <lastmod>2013-12-06</lastmod>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>0.6</priority>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://localhost:11149/en/News"/>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="nl" href="http://localhost:11149/nl/News"/>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

Comment: You need to show your controller method. Also what does the Raw HTTP look like?

Comment: @Liam I added the html, the controller has nothing to with it as it return a XmlSiteMapResult, nothing happens except filling the list of items.

Comment: If you look at site map (xdocument) does it look like well formatted XML at that point?

Comment: According to MSDN this is a valid sitemap: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy2ykkab(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Indeed the sitemap validates perfect whenever I let a website validate it. Although I would like that whenever a customer goes to sitemap he sees it with the browsers xml viewer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what we do to generate the sitemap for autoquoter.com. See http://www.autoquoter.com/aq/sitemap.xml

```
        var sitemap = new XDocument(
            new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
            new XProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet",
                "type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"" + Url.AbsoluteAction("SitemapXsl", "Default") + "\""),
            new XElement(ns + "urlset",
                new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "sitemap", ns),
                new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xhtml", xhtml), 
                nodeList));

        Response.AddHeader("X-Robots-Tag","noindex");
        return Content(sitemap.Declaration+"\r\n"+sitemap, "text/xml");
```

We also use an xsl stylesheet to transform the sitemap. This helps with browsers that don't provide a decent formatter automatically. See http://www.autoquoter.com/aq/en/Default/SitemapXsl for the stylesheet that we are using.

Comment: This was what I was looking for, so you use an xls to transform the xml in the browser. Nice solution thanks!

Answer (score 1):

EDIT 1:

It seems that you may lose some of the xml specific header files:

[Check this link out](http://store.cascadepools.co.uk/feeds/CascadePoolsStore_gs.xml)

This might also be a valid example on how to create an xml site map:

[Sitemap xml for google](http://blog.divergencehosting.com/2009/04/01/dynamic-create-google-sitemap-aspnet/)
[Another example](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2005/12/02/432188.aspx)
**OPTION1**
Try this code out(taken from [here](http://joelabrahamsson.com/xml-sitemap-with-aspnet/)):

```
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    public class Sitemap : IHttpHandler
    {
        private const string NAMESPACE = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9";

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
            XmlDocument sitemapDocument = GetSitemapDocument();
            context.Response.Write(sitemapDocument.InnerXml);
        }

        #region Build sitemap document methods
        private XmlDocument GetSitemapDocument()
        {
            XmlDocument sitemapDocument = new XmlDocument();
            sitemapDocument.PreserveWhitespace = true;

            XmlDeclaration xmlDeclaration = 
                sitemapDocument.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", string.Empty);
            sitemapDocument.AppendChild(xmlDeclaration);

            XmlElement urlset = sitemapDocument.CreateElement("urlset", NAMESPACE);
            sitemapDocument.AppendChild(urlset);

            List<SitemapPage> urls = GetSitemapPages();

            foreach (SitemapPage sitemapPage in urls)
            {
                XmlElement url = CreateUrlElement(sitemapDocument, sitemapPage);
                urlset.AppendChild(url);
            }
            return sitemapDocument;
        }

        private XmlElement CreateUrlElement(XmlDocument sitemapDocument, 
            SitemapPage sitemapPage)
        {
            XmlElement url = sitemapDocument.CreateElement("url", NAMESPACE);

            XmlElement loc = CreateElementWithText(sitemapDocument, "loc", 
                sitemapPage.Location);
            url.AppendChild(loc);

            if (sitemapPage.LastModificationDate.HasValue)
            {
                //lastmod must be a string that comforms to the W3C Datetime format
                string lastModValue = sitemapPage.LastModificationDate.Value.ToString(
                    "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ssK");
                XmlElement lastmod = CreateElementWithText(
                    sitemapDocument, "lastmod", lastModValue);
                url.AppendChild(lastmod);
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sitemapPage.ChangeFrequency))
            {
                XmlElement changefreq = CreateElementWithText(sitemapDocument, 
                    "changefreq", sitemapPage.ChangeFrequency);
                url.AppendChild(changefreq);
            }

            if (sitemapPage.Priority.HasValue)
            {
                XmlElement priority = CreateElementWithText(sitemapDocument,
                    "priority", sitemapPage.Priority.Value.ToString(
                        CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")));
                url.AppendChild(priority);
            }

            return url;
        }

        private XmlElement CreateElementWithText(
            XmlDocument document, string elementName, string text)
        {
            XmlElement element = document.CreateElement(elementName, NAMESPACE);

            XmlText elementValue = document.CreateTextNode(text);
            element.AppendChild(elementValue);

            return element;
        }
        #endregion

        private List<SitemapPage> GetSitemapPages()
        {
            List<SitemapPage> sitemapPages = new List<SitemapPage>();

            //Example implementation
            sitemapPages.Add(new SitemapPage("http://www.mydomain.com") 
                { ChangeFrequency = "daily", LastModificationDate = DateTime.Now, Priority = 1f });
            sitemapPages.Add(new SitemapPage("http://www.mydomain.com/aPage.aspx") 
                { ChangeFrequency = "daily", LastModificationDate = DateTime.Now, Priority = 0.8f });

            return sitemapPages;
        }

        private class SitemapPage
        {
            public SitemapPage(string location)
            {
                Location = location;
            }

            public string Location { get; private set; }
            public DateTime? LastModificationDate { get; set; }
            public string ChangeFrequency { get; set; }
            public float? Priority { get; set; }
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

**OPTION2:** According to MSDN this is a valid sitemap: [sitemap MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy2ykkab%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Check this output out:

```
<siteMap>
  <siteMapNode title="Home" description="Home" url="~/default.aspx">
    <siteMapNode title="Products" description="Our products"
      url="~/Products.aspx">
      <siteMapNode title="Hardware" description="Hardware choices"
        url="~/Hardware.aspx" />
      <siteMapNode title="Software" description="Software choices"
        url="~/Software.aspx" />
    </siteMapNode>
    <siteMapNode title="Services" description="Services we offer"
        url="~/Services.aspx">
        <siteMapNode title="Training" description="Training classes"
          url="~/Training.aspx" />
        <siteMapNode title="Consulting" description="Consulting services" 
          url="~/Consulting.aspx" />
        <siteMapNode title="Support" description="Supports plans" 
          url="~/Support.aspx" />
    </siteMapNode>
  </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

Maybe you should try change your code:

```
public class XmlSitemapResult : ActionResult
{
    private XNamespace nsSitemap = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9";
    private XNamespace nsXhtml = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";

    private IEnumerable<SitemapItem> _items;

    public XmlSitemapResult(IEnumerable<SitemapItem> items)
    {
        _items = items;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        string encoding = context.HttpContext.Response.ContentEncoding.WebName;
        XDocument sitemap = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", encoding, "yes"),
             new XElement(nsSitemap + "siteMap", new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xhtml", nsXhtml),
                  from item in _items
                  select CreateItemElement(item)
                  )
             );

        context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/xml";
        context.HttpContext.Response.Charset = encoding;
        context.HttpContext.Response.Flush();
        context.HttpContext.Response.Write(sitemap.Declaration + sitemap.ToString());
    }

    private XElement CreateItemElement(SitemapItem item)
    {
        XElement itemElement = new XElement(nsSitemap + "siteMapNode", new XElement(nsSitemap + "loc", item.Url.ToLower()));

        if (item.LastModified.HasValue)
            itemElement.Add(new XElement(nsSitemap + "lastmod", item.LastModified.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")));

        if (item.ChangeFrequency.HasValue)
            itemElement.Add(new XElement(nsSitemap + "changefreq", item.ChangeFrequency.Value.ToString().ToLower()));

        if (item.Priority.HasValue)
            itemElement.Add(new XElement(nsSitemap + "priority", item.Priority.Value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));

        foreach (var alternateLink in item.AlternateLinks)
        {
            itemElement.Add(new XElement(nsXhtml + "link", 
                new XAttribute("rel", "alternate"),
                new XAttribute("hreflang", alternateLink.Language),
                new XAttribute("href", alternateLink.Url)));
        }

        return itemElement;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Although both don't work with the xhtml alternate links. Also the sidemap nodes I used are straight from google so I suppose those are the once I want to use. I don't know if there would be any difference between them for search engines but as said before they don't support the alternate links. And I believe it goes wrong there.

Comment: Yes I looked at both, both don't use the xhtml alternate link which causes the problem. If I don't use the xhtml tags it does show as XML in my browser.

Comment: I think the problem is that you don't include the namespaces, and XML start node and rest of mandatory xml header stuff. Check this one: http://store.cascadepools.co.uk/feeds/CascadePoolsStore_gs.xml

Comment: I'll try to add those, I'll get back to you when I did this. (will be later today)

Comment: I added the other headers but it didn't help. I really think it has something to do with the xhtml. (which isn't in any of your examples)

Comment: the problem is not that xml doesn't work because it validates fine at google. But because of the following lines:  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://localhost:11149/en/Partner"/>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="nl" href="http://localhost:11149/nl/Partner"/> it won't show as XML in the browser.

Comment: Then here is your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19200160/xml-sitemap-not-displaying-in-xml-format

Comment: Also here is what you should set as content type: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272534/what-content-type-value-should-i-send-for-my-xml-sitemap

Comment: yup none worked. I guess you can't show a xml with xhtml as an xml in the browser.

Comment: I still don't confirmation on that fact so there is no answer. Also the question can be helpfull for others that have the same problem (it's not like I'm the only one who ever added xhtml to the sitemap, because google has it in their own guides). Also you shouldn't focus that badly on the bounty. The bounty will be awarded if I get the answer, if the bounty period is gone the answer with the most points will automaticly get half of the points so don't worry.

Comment: The above comment was for another (now deleted) comment. Anyway my quesiton still isn't answered and stays open till there is a valid answer.

Comment: Julian, did you find an answer? I'm having the same problem with alternate node.

Comment: @MansurKhan Nope, still haven't gotten any answer that satisfied. I suppose a browser just doesn't render it in the XMLViewer when it has an xhtml tag in it.

Comment: It does not work because of the content type. I tried it on .net.